# Trigonometry equation $\tan2x+3 \sec x +3=0$ for $0\leq x\leq 360$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the trigonometry equation for $0\leq x\leq 360$

$$\tan2x+3 \sec x +3=0$$

I've no idea how should I start. Is there any identity I've to use? Hope someone can show out the working and explain for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x=180°$ is a solution...

Comment: A general method: choose a function, for example $\cos$ and try to express your equation uniquely in terms of $X:=\cos x$, if possible as a polynomial in $X$, find the real roots $X_k$ of this polynomial, then solve the different equations $\cos(x)=X_k$.

Comment: Beyond $180°$, there are at least 3 other  solutions, but none has a simple expression in degrees. Are you expected to find solutions such as $x=arctan(0.8976...)$?. Maybe check your equation...

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $\cos2x\cos x\ne0$

Multiply both sides of the given equation $$\cos x\sin2x+3(1+\cos x)\cos2x=0$$

$$0=2\sin x\cos^2x+3(1+\cos x)\cos2x$$

$$=4\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2\cos^2x+3\cdot2\cos^2\dfrac x2\cos2x$$

$$=2\cos\dfrac x2\left(2\sin\dfrac x2\cos^2x+3\cos\dfrac x2\cos2x\right)$$

If $\cos\dfrac x2=0,\dfrac x2=(2n+1)90^\circ\implies x=(2n+1)180^\circ\equiv180^\circ\pmod{360^\circ}$

Else  $2\sin\dfrac x2\cos^2x+3\cos\dfrac x2\cos2x=0$

$-2\tan\dfrac x2=\dfrac{3(2\cos^2x-1)}{\cos^2x}$

Use $\cos x=\dfrac{1-\tan^2\dfrac x2}{1+\tan^2\dfrac x2}$ which unfortunately leaves us with a bi-quadratic equation in $\tan\dfrac x2$

Answer (score 0):

I got some general hints and one (already mentioned) solution:

First - Rewrite in terms that are more familiar:
$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and $\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x}$ so we get:

$\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x} + \frac{3}{\cos x} = -3$

Second - Try some easy to calculate values (90, 180, 270, 360 degree)

Now we can already see, that if $\sin 2x = 0$ and $\cos x = -1$ the equation is true. Thats $180°$.

Third - Use the derivative to see what happens in between. I leave that to you ;)

Answer (score -1):

Hint in $[0,\pi]$.

let $f(x)=\tan(2x)+\frac{3}{\cos(x)}+3$

$$f'(x)=2(1+\tan^2(2x))+\frac{3\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$

$f$ is continuous and strictly increasing in $[0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ ,$(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$, $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{4})$ and $(\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi]$

so in $(\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi]$, the only solution is

$x=\pi$.

Comment: I' am sorry but it's not exact. The fact that a function is increasing does not entail that has no zeroes.

Comment: just to purpose an other approach.

Comment: But it is not another approach. It is erroneous. And the best proof is that there are two roots in $[0,\pi]$, approx. 0.85 and 2.16 radians.